# How to change wpf listviewitem background color when its data is using binding?

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm trying to change listview's row background color for a data binding listview.

From msdn, I know there is ListViewsItem.Backgroud for the color of its background.

But since I'm using data binding for ListView's data source,the type of ListView's item is actually my class type, no longer ListViewItem. So I can't find its Background property.

I guess I missed something, how should I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set ItemContainerStyle of your listview like below to set any property on item.

```
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>  
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

You even change the background depending of dataitem state using triggers in style.